Flutter app version checking : application version and Playstore and Appstore
Check new version is available in appstore and plastore using application version ,
If new version is available show alert message and update.
if no update in playstore and appstore app work normally

You can use upgrader package to do this. This package provides an easy way to check for updates and show a dialog when a new version is available.
like this :
Future<void> _checkForUpdates() async {
    // Use the Upgrader package to check for updates
    await Upgrader().checkForUpdate(context: context);
}

call this method to check for update and show dialog
